# performing mathematical functions across a data_frame

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot

I have the following df. I would like to group by ID and do Fy=(Fyb+Fya)/2 for every column that ends with charts. If any of the two values is NA, an NA output would do.

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("51-07519", "51-07519", "51-07522", "51-07522", 
"51-07525", "51-07525"), name = c("Fya", "Fyb", "Fya", "Fyb", 
"Fya", "Fyb"), serology_charts = c("0", "0", "0", "0", NA, NA
), antibodies_charts = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), bioarray_charts = c(NA, 
NA, "0", "0", NA, NA), others_charts = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

> ```
>   ID       name  serology_charts antibodies_charts bioarray_charts others_charts
>   <chr>    <chr> <chr>           <chr>             <chr>           <chr>        
> 1 51-07519 Fya   0               NA                NA              NA           
> 2 51-07519 Fyb   0               NA                NA              NA           
> 3 51-07522 Fya   0               NA                0               NA           
> 4 51-07522 Fyb   0               NA                0               NA           
> 5 51-07525 Fya   NA              NA                NA              NA           
> 6 51-07525 Fyb   NA              NA                NA              NA
> ```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

> ```
>    ID       name  serology_charts antibodies_charts bioarray_charts others_charts
>   <chr>    <chr> <chr>           <chr>             <chr>           <chr>        
> 1 51-07519 Fy   0               NA                NA              NA           
> 2 51-07522 Fy   0               NA                0               NA           
> 3 51-07525 Fy   NA              NA                NA              NA
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can first convert the column types with `type.convert`, then do a `group_by` `summarise_at` (and if needed convert the columns back to `character` - not clear why the columns are character)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   summarise_at(vars(ends_with('charts')),
         ~ if(any(is.na(.))) NA_real_ else sum(., na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
   mutate(name = 'Fy') %>%
   mutate_at(vars(ends_with('charts')), as.character) %>%
   select(names(df))
# A tibble: 3 x 6
#  ID       name  serology_charts antibodies_charts bioarray_charts others_charts
#  <chr>    <chr> <chr>           <chr>             <chr>           <chr>        
#1 51-07519 Fy    0               <NA>              <NA>            <NA>         
#2 51-07522 Fy    0               <NA>              0               <NA>         
#3 51-07525 Fy    <NA>            <NA>              <NA>            <NA>
```

If we need to pass a different function based on the value in 'name'

```
df %>%
    type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
     summarise_at(vars(ends_with('charts')),
         ~ if(any(is.na(.))) NA_real_ else
            (.[name == "Fyb"]+1)*(.[name == "Fya"])/2)
```

Comment: when defining the function `sum(., na.rm = TRUE)`, is it possible to define a function based on the value in the $name column? Let's say (Fyb+1)*Fya/2. I have to try a few of these to find out what works